# Is Patrick Melrose referencing The 400 Blows?

Tags: reference, the-400-blows, patrick-melrose

Not a Truffaut expert, but the main thing I remember from the [The 400 Blows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_400_Blows) is lots of shots of the kid running through fields. *(Tracking shots, if memory serves.)*

The *Patrick Melrose* television show is also about the effects of child abuse, and features numerous, similar shots of the young Patrick running through the vineyard on his parents' estate.

- For those who have seen both, does it seem like a reference?

If so, are there other Truffaut references I'm missing?